# CMDT Enhanced Related Lists New button is broken

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

We are using CMDT Enhanced Related Lists for a while now.  When Spring 20 release was deployed into our sandbox, the New button on one of our list instances no longer works.

We are using a custom component as the "New" button override, and per the CMDT Enhanced list documentation, I only need to include 2 attributes, parentFieldName and parentFieldId:

[image]

Our component has been working fine up until Spring 20 was put in our sandbox.  Now those 2 attributes are no longer being set as expected...

Here's what we get now when the component loads:
[image]

Is anyone else able to reproduce this?  I'm trying to see if I need to escalate this to Salesforc Labs team to try to get this fixed asap.